# How to get scope properties from $route?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm beginner with AngularJS and I have problem with kind of $scope:

[image: my code screen]

```js
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {

   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function() {
   console.log($route.current);
   document.title = $route.current.scope.title;

   });
}]);
```

Here is my console screen:

[image: Console screen]

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think scope is tied to $route?

Comment: In Console Screen show it. I saw.